# K&R Exercise 2-7, optimisations?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, kernighan-and-ritchie

I'm currently learning C with "The C Programming Language" from K&R. I solved the exercise 2-7, which says:

> Write a function `invert(x,p,n)` that returns `x` with the `n` bits that begin at position `p` inverted (i.e., 1 changed into 0 and vice versa), leaving the other bits unchanged.

Here is my code (I voluntarily used chars here):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUMBER   235
#define POSITION 2
#define AMOUNT   4

unsigned invert(unsigned char x, char p, char n)
{
    unsigned char bitsToInvert = 0, i;

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) { // Make a number n-bits width, full of 1
        bitsToInvert |= 1;
        bitsToInvert <<= 1;
    }
    bitsToInvert |= 1;

    bitsToInvert <<= p;

    x ^= bitsToInvert;

    return x;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", invert(NUMBER, POSITION, AMOUNT));
}
```

Is there any optimisation I could bring to my code? Especially on the `for` loop which create a number of `n` 1 bits?
Thanks!

Comment: `2^n - 1` or `(1<<n) -1` will give you last n bits set. :)

Comment: you should have at-least used `unsigned chars`.

Comment: There is an other exercise that asks you to *set* a range of bits, this is just a xor with that.

Comment: Here is a solution : http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/K%26R2_solutions:Chapter_2:Exercise_7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2^n - 1`  is always a number with all `n` LSB bits set.

For eg:

```
2 ^ 3 - 1 = 7  => 111
2 ^ 5 - 1 = 31 => 11111
```

In your case, you can do away with the for loop to construct this number by simply saying:

```
bitsToConvert = (1<<n) - 1;
```

Dont forget to take care of extreme situations.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think enough about it. ^^

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to what Thrustmaster said, that would work for any "n" without the need for specifying it, would be using a bitwise not on an empty value.

```
variable = ~(variable ^ variable);
```